# How to view SVG files in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I have uploaded a SVG file to Google Drive.  When I try to view it by double clicking on the file in my Drive account, I get this view:

[image]

Why? I thought that SVG files would be pretty ubiquitously supported and especially by Google's cloud infrastructure?  What I'm expecting is to have it viewed just like a HTML web page such that if I have links associated with parts of the SVG file, I can click on them. I really do not want to have to convert the SVG file to something like PNG or PDF if I can avoid it (i.e., I am not asking a conversion question such as at [Import SVG files to Google Docs as a drawing](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18793/import-svg-files-to-google-docs-as-a-drawing)).

Answer (score 1):

I found out only [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30654/in-google-drive-how-can-you-link-directly-to-download-a-zip-file-and-not-view?rq=1) which is equivalent as click on the download button and then open the downloaded file in any browser (supporting SVG) for visualisation or inkscape and so on for edition.

(The previously proposed answer is providing the customization of the download url)

Answer (score 0):

In the `Connect Apps to Google Drive` section (`New > More > Connect New Apps`), there is a "Document Viewer for Drive" app that claims to be able to show SVG files. I have not tested it, and it appears to have ok reviews, but it may be able to help.

Comment: Not. This app does not support .svg within Google Drive: *Google Drive Support: jpeg, png, gif, tiff, bmp, webm, mp4, mkv, m4v, mp3, ogv, wmv, flv, txt, css, html, psd, dxf, ttf, zip, rar...* And, empirically, it does not work. An attempt to insert an .svg into a Google Doc after installation gives the message "The file you selected was not a valid image file." This is the same message that was displayed prior to installation.

Comment: @wchlm I guess it must've been updated

Answer (score 0):

Use Cloud Converter 3rd party app and convert to a zip file. You can then download it to your windows explorer program and open it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried sending the SVG files on my PC to Google Files on my Android phone via Bluetooth before uploading it to Google Drive from my Android phone. I have tried this method successfully, finally the SVG file can be seen on Google Drive.

[image]
[image]
[image]